# Python asyncio.Event class gives error with different tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am trying setup a flag for my async loop. I tried using asyncio.Event but I get a RuntimeError
Here's my code:

```
import sys
import asyncio
import logging

root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setFormatter(
    logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s %(message)s')
)
root.addHandler(ch)

global event
event = asyncio.Event()

class AsyncTest():
    async def bg(self):
        root.debug('Waiting for 10 secs')
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        event.set()
        root.debug('Setted Event')

    async def waiter(self):
        event.clear()

        root.debug('Created task')
        asyncio.create_task(self.bg())
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

        root.debug('waiting')
        await event.wait()
        root.debug('Finished Waiting.')
        return


async def main():
    obj = AsyncTest()
    await obj.waiter()

asyncio.run(main())
```

The bg courotine does a periodic task. Therefore it has to be run in asyncio.create_task() .
The waiter coroutine is called at multiple points to wait until the event is set.
So while running this i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python Programs\Python\KLibs\NeuralConnect\test\test.py", line 39, in main
    await obj.waiter()
  File "C:\Python Programs\Python\KLibs\NeuralConnect\test\test.py", line 32, in waiter
    await event.wait()
  File "C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\locks.py", line 293, in wait
    await fut
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<main() running at C:\Python Programs\Python\KLibs\NeuralConnect\test\test.py:39> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:157]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

can anyone point out what is wrong in my above implementation? Also how should I correct? Should abandon the asyncio.Event() part and then use a bool variable?

The problem using the bool flag variable is that I have to do:

```
cond = False
while not cond:
    await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
```

I find this un-pythonic. Is there any better implementation of this, incase asyncio.Event isnt suitable?

Comment: You should create the event in `main()` by putting `global event; event = asyncio Event()` there. Creating it at top-level creates it under a different event loop, causing problems later.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I recieved an answer to this problem from alex_normane who answered a question linked to this. It seems that the asyncio.Event object has to passed as parameter to the coroutine in create_task(). Plus the asyncio.Event object must be created within a coroutine as also stated by user4815162342.

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65353254/13574717