# Python Asyncio - Pythonic way of waiting until condition satisfied

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I need to wait until a certain condition/equation becomes True in a asynchronous function in python.
Basically it is a flag variable which would be flagged by a coroutine running in asyncio.create_task(). I want to await until it is flagged in the main loop of asyncio.
Here's my current code:

```
import asyncio
flag = False

async def bg_tsk():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    flag = True

async def waiter():
    asyncio.create_task(bg_tsk())
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    # I find the below part unpythonic
    while not flag:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)

asyncio.run(waiter())
```

Is there any better implementation of this? Or is this the best way possible? I have tried using 'asyncio.Event', but it doesnt seem to work with 'asyncio.create_task()'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using of [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) is quite straightforward. Sample below.

*Note*: Event should be created from inside coroutine for correct work.

```
import asyncio


async def bg_tsk(flag):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    flag.set()


async def waiter():
    flag = asyncio.Event()
    asyncio.create_task(bg_tsk(flag))
    await flag.wait()
    print("After waiting")


asyncio.run(waiter())
```

Comment: I think `asyncio.sleep(0)` is useless here, or i'm missing something?

Comment: Actually the await asyncio.sleep(0) makes sure that the control goes to create_task to start it immediately. If not used, the task will start only after the program encounters await somewhere else. But thanks this works... I just have to try to check whether passing a list of Events would work....

Comment: @cyberGhoul Note that an `await` will be encountered immediately because you'll be waiting for the flag. `asyncio.sleep(0)` is very rarely needed, and its use typically points to an architectural or design issue with the code.

Comment: What about when you have no control over the launch of the function you want to wait for?