# How to pull `asyncio.event.set()` outside of the `async def` context?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a `waiter()` function which I start running. Subsequently, an event such as a click on an `ipywidgets.Button` should modify the result. My idea is to use `event.set()` through the `Button` click, thus I pulled `event.set()` outside the asyncio context. However,since the `waiter()` function is blocked, the click-action is also blocked. I think that calling `event.set()` in some other function should be a common necessity, but I'm using `asyncio` wrong. What should I be doing instead?

Code modified from:[Python Asyncio - Pythonic way of waiting until condition satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352682/python-asyncio-pythonic-way-of-waiting-until-condition-satisfied)

```py
import asyncio
from ipywidgets import Button

async def event_done(btn):
    event1.set()
    print('registred a click')
    
run_button = Button(description='continue')
run_button.on_click(event_done)

event1  = asyncio.Event()
async def waiter(event1):
    # event1 = asyncio.Event()
    print('waiting')
    # event1.set()
    await event1.wait()
    print("After waiting")

display(run_button)
asyncio.run(waiter(event1))
```

Comment: Why are you using asyncio at all for this? A simple thread event would work as well with less cruft.

Comment: Probably want to use `loop.run_in_executor` to wait on a threading.Lock / Semaphore or populate some Queue object that is populated outside of the asyncio loop

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I think I agree. Upon your sugestion I tried a very simple `event1.wait()`, but the `on_click()` is not registred.

Comment: I can only assume that this is due to how IPython/Jupyter runs code, not the code itself. Basically what you need are two threads of control (one for triggering the event, one for waiting on the event) in the same process. That is not how the ipython kernels work, they will just run what you tell them directly so there is just one thread of control by default and it is a separate process from the UI. You would at the very least have to create an actual `threading.Thread` or `asyncio.Task` to wait for the event in the background.